# using jint to call javascript using d3 from c#

Tags: javascript, c#, d3.js, svg, jint

I am currently working on a project where we need to generate some SVG based on some input data. Currently all this SVG generation is implemented in javascript using the d3 library. Note that my goal is to be able to reuse this logic and not implement it all over.

My problem is that I would like to be able to call this javascript from C#.

I have tried using PhantomJS and I am able to generate the SVG but I am not satisfied because

- Each time I want to call the javascript it starts a new process and I
  have noticed that it uses a lot of memory (In my case I saw 100 mb
  which is too much in my case)
- It seems a little unstable. I have
  had some cases where the process just hangs
- Development (On the javascript side) is pretty frustrating because it is hard to debug

Because I was not satisfied with PhantomJS I have also tried using jint and this seems really nice to work with. Unfortunately I haven't quite managed to get a working example up and running. Currently I am using AngleSharp to supply the DOM so that D3 has a place to write its data. This gives me the following example:

```
static void TestJint()
    {
        //We require a custom configuration with JavaScript and CSS
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithJavaScript().WithCss();
        //Let's create a new parser using this configuration
        var parser = new HtmlParser(config);

        //This is our sample source, we will do some DOM manipulation
        var source = "<!doctype html> <html><head></head> <body> </body></html>";
        var document = parser.Parse(source);



        var jintEngine = new Engine();

        jintEngine.SetValue("document", document.Implementation);


        jintEngine = jintEngine.Execute(File.ReadAllText("d3.min.js"));


        jintEngine = jintEngine.Execute("function testFunc() { d3.select(\"body\").append(\"span\").text(\"Hello, world!\"); return 42;}");

        var res = jintEngine.Invoke("testFunc").ToObject();

    }
```

The problem is that the line var res = jintEngine.Invoke("testFunc").ToObject(); throws an exception.

[Exception screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVJq0.png)

If I try replacing the line

```
        jintEngine = jintEngine.Execute("function testFunc() { d3.select(\"body\").append(\"span\").text(\"Hello, world!\"); return 42;}");
```

with

```
        jintEngine = jintEngine.Execute("function testFunc() { d3.select(\"body\"); return 42;}");
```

then the function is able to run without any exceptions. By playing a little with the logic I have concluded that it is the .append(\"span\") that causes the exception.

I am a little stuck so I was hoping that someone might have an idea that could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the problems.

1) The document returned by parser.Parse(source); does not implement the function createElementNS which d3 uses. I solved this by using a wrapper that delegates the call.

2) d3 uses the variable ownerDocument which I havn't set. So I also had to add the following

```
jintEngine.SetValue("ownerDocument", new MyDocumentWrapper(document));
```

Note that this doesn't make the entire d3 library work. I have also noticed some problems with d3.geopath() but with these fixes I am able to execute my initial example.